# creating log file of specific web traffic statistics

Tags: web, traffic

I have a website, hosted on a shared server.
Through CPANEL, I am provided with a few traffic analysis logs and tools.
None seem to provide what I'm looking for.
For each day, I'd like to see log file with a list of unique visitors.
  Under each unique visitor (by IP address), I'd like to see the following information
     geographic location (based on IP address)
     information to help determine if the visitor was a bot or human 
     the page URLs they requested (including the exact time of request)

explanation of my application:
    I run a forum on my site. I'd like a better understanding of who is visiting, when they visit and how
      they navigate through my forum pages (topics, posts etc.)

I would appreciate some direction on how to develop this (a script is probably best)

Answer (score 3):

I would (and do) use Google Analytics as it gives you exactly what you are asking for and a whole lot more (like being able to see live what is happening). It requires you to add some javascript code to the application (which for so many today, plugins are available).

If no plugin is available, see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

This approach to your end result will typically be a lot easier than trying to create your own log analyser and installing it on a shared cPanel server.